# Objective-C Incorrect Format Specifiers

Tags: objective-c, format, scanf, specifier

I am trying to learn Objective-C and the book i am learning from presents some code for me to type into Xcode. I keep receiving warnings on the `scanf` function for incorrect format specifiers even though this is how it is typed in the book. The code is as follows

```
@autoreleasepool {

    double value1 = 0.0, value2 = 0.0;

    char operator = '\0';


    scanf("%lf %c %lf", value1, operator, value2);

    }
```

Comment: The build warning should tell you what's wrong and Xcode will often offer to fix it for you if you tap the build warning.

Comment: No, this is not how it's typed in the book. `scanf()` needs to modify its arguments - now think about how it will be possible. Or read some sample code using `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't studied pointers probably you'll see it later: to modify a variable you need it's address , otherwise you don't modify the original value, but just a copy. So scanf expects pointers as arguments:

```
scanf("%lf %c %lf", &value1, &operator, &value2);
```

Comment: Thank you. I know a little bit about pointers but i keep forgetting to use them.